# Salesforce tab name different for users

Tags: tab

Why does different profile have separate tab names for same object?

When I log in to the Salesforce, I do see the knowledge base on tab as "Article" with link https://company--qa.cs14.my.salesforce.com/knowledge/knowledgeHome.apexp.

But when logged in as another user who has the same permission(when looking based on article) but on different profile does not have this link on the user tab. But I do see "Knowledge" on it with link https://company--qa.cs14.my.salesforce.com/_ui/knowledge/ui/KnowledgeHome
They both show the same content but with different look and feel and layout.

I did checked the "tab name and labels" under setup > customize, but don't see any entry for this. Also I checked for any apex pages created for this, but 
don't see them too.

Any clue where this is set or where to look into?

Comment: Resolved it!!

There is a General user permission that reads "Knowledge One". If that is enabled, then Knowledge tab will be displayed. If disabled "Article" tab will be displayed. I enabled "Knowledge One" and it worked.

More info on Articles vs Knowledge:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_articles.htm&language=en_US

Comment: You can post that as a solution to your question. If possible, include a link to any applicable documentation for that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it!!

There is a General user permission that reads "Knowledge One". If that is enabled, then Knowledge tab will be displayed. If disabled "Article" tab will be displayed. I enabled "Knowledge One" and it worked.

More info on Articles vs Knowledge:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_articles.htm&language=en_US